# trying to click a button on a pop up

Tags: pywinauto

Hi I am trying to click a button on a pop up to install something.

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application()
app.WindowsSecurity.Install.Click()
```

This code is working fine for Windows 2k8 but on Windows 2k12 is not working.
I think because of the GUI change it's not happening. I am able to catch the pop up but not able to click on the install button. I am getting control identifiers. Can you help me in order to click on that button?

[Control Identifiers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpcDl.jpg)

Comment: What is the output / traceback of the script? It should be more useful than `print_control_identifiers()` output.

Comment: on execution of the above code i am getting no output.. only the pop up box is getting selected.. and after that nothing is happening.
Tried this also :
a = app.connect(title_re = "Windows.*")
window.SetFocus()
window.Install.Click()

Comment: Did you try `ClickInput()` instead? or running as Administrator?

Comment: I am getting the following error & yes I am running it as an administrator:
window.Install.ClickInput()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.5.4-py2.7.egg\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py", line 900, in ClickIn
put
 self, button, coords, double, wheel_dist = wheel_dist, use_log = use_log, pressed = pressed, absolute = absolute)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.5.4-py2.7.egg\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py", line 1778, in _perfo
rm_click_input
    win32api.SetCursorPos((coords[0], coords[1]))
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')

Comment: It means that UAC is enabled. You need to disable UAC to zero level to be able to automate the task.

Comment: UAC is already at zero level. I am running the code in Windows Server 2012 64bit

Comment: and 64-bit Python?

Comment: It looks like RazerX has the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835890/installing-unsigned-drivers

Comment: It looks the problem is not on pywinauto side. But you can try one more workaround: use something like `app.WindowsSecurity.TypeKeys('{LEFT}{ENTER}')` to press `Install`.

Comment: yes 64 bit python.. 
yes i am also facing the exact prob..i want to put this in a script which is installing some components

Comment: app.WindowsSecurity.TypeKeys('{LEFT}{ENTER}')
tried this.. this is also not working

Comment: OK, try to `Disable driver signature enforcement` ([instruction for WinServer2012](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emberger/2014/04/21/windows-server-2012-r2-install-unsigned-drivers/)).

Comment: for my scenario this thing will not work... as the script will run on different different environment... and plus i tried this.. it not working.. ! have to find a way to click on install button only